# nodejs - Temporary file name

Tags: node.js

In node.js, how do I generate a unique temporary file name, a la `mkstemp(3)`? I want to atomically write a file using `fs.rename`.

Comment: This is not a tool recommendation. This is question whether an API exists. I mean what the hell, 90% SO questions are about whether some API exists to do something. Close them all or none.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Maybe you already found [node-temp](https://github.com/bruce/node-temp) in the meantime.

Answer (score 55):

Another popular package is [tmp](https://npmjs.org/package/tmp).

Comment: why is this the real answer?

Comment: For once, the tmp package is more popular these days.  Second, there are a few minor advantages documented @ https://github.com/raszi/node-tmp/blob/master/README.md#about

Comment: @k0pernikus you can find up to date examples at the library site

Comment: Note that this package makes use of the `os.tempdir()` method. On MacOS, this can cause issues as it returns a symlink – not an absolute path.

Answer (score 24):

Without using any additional plugins:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var fs = require('fs'); 

var filename = 'foo'+crypto.randomBytes(4).readUInt32LE(0)+'bar';
fs.writeFileSync(filename, 'baz');
```

EDIT: read comments.

Comment: Careful, this is a classic antipattern that is very dangerous! This kind of code has resulted in many vulnerabilities over the years, and it is the exact reason that mkstemp was created to replace mktemp. To be secure, the file should be opened with both the O_CREAT and O_EXCL flags, to prevent another user from predicting the filename and creating a symlink there before you can write to it. I suppose if you're absolutely sure that another user couldn't predict the filename in a million years, it's not necessary, but why chance it? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink_race

Comment: I don't think there is enough entropy in that filename, it outputs `foo1492796329bar` a SHA1 with a random salt would be better

Comment: Josue, I agree that 32 bits of entropy is too little. 64 bits should be enough for short-lived files, though. Why do you suggest a hash if we already have a random value?

Comment: Given the fact the other 2 answers recommend installing arbitrary code that runs arbitrary code on install, arbitrarily changes over time, depends on several other packages and is horribly overengineered, this approach is better anyway.

Comment: @Geoff crypto secure random bytes cannot be predicted.   The only issue is that the user should have done: `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64').replace(/\//,'_')`.  In my experience, mktemp has serious cross-platform problems as well as possible hangs/breaking issues.

Comment: @ErikAronesty There are other characters you may need to replace, and you should specify the `g` option to replace more than the first match.

Comment: @bort yeah, i was thinking python.  base64 is a pretty limited set... what other characters do you need?

Answer (score 12):

Temp file creation in node and python suffer from race conditions involving permission changes, and cross-platform issues, especially on Windows where it's challenging to test ACL's.

The result is that it can literally hang your machine asking for a temp file in many modern languages.  (If node doesn't have access to the temp dir, depending on the ACLs, it can get EEXIST, even when the file doesn't exist - the result of which can be an infinite loop.).

The simplest solution is to use enough entropy that the likelihood of a collision is negligible (in the cryptographic sense).

This also has the side effect of making temp file creation secure across all platforms, without needing to heavily vet the source code.  As long as your random numbers are secure, there is no way to predict the file that will be used to usurp permissions or access.

And it helps with programs that need to pass file names around, not file handles.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const os = require('os'); 
const path = require('path'); 

function tmpFile(prefix, suffix, tmpdir) {
    prefix = (typeof prefix !== 'undefined') ? prefix : 'tmp.';
    suffix = (typeof suffix !== 'undefined') ? suffix : '';
    tmpdir = tmpdir ? tmpdir : os.tmpdir();
    return path.join(tmpdir, prefix + crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') + suffix);
}
```

The only disadvantage is that this will not work on FAT formatted partitions, which can still be common on USB sticks.

Answer (score 9):

Try this function, secure and without vulnerabilities. NODE 8.x LTS

```
function tempFile (name = 'temp_file', data = '', encoding = 'utf8') {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const os = require('os');
    const path = require('path');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const tempPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'foobar-');
        fs.mkdtemp(tempPath, (err, folder) => {
            if (err) 
                return reject(err)

            const file_name = path.join(folder, name);

            fs.writeFile(file_name, data, encoding, error_file => {
                if (error_file) 
                    return reject(error_file);

                resolve(file_name)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

It resolves the PATH of the temp file, rejects mkdtemp or writeFile errors

```
// C:\Users\MYPC\AppData\Local\Temp\foobar-3HmKod\temp_file
// /temp/Temp/foobar-3HmKod/temp_file
tempFile().then(path => console.log(path)).catch(e => console.log("error", e)) //or

// C:\Users\MYPC\AppData\Local\Temp\foobar-9KHuxg\hola.txt
// /temp/Temp/foobar-9KHuxg/hola.txt
tempFile('hola.txt', 'hello there').then(path => console.log(path)).catch(e => console.log("e", e))
```

Comment: Claiming that this code is "secure and without vulnerabilities" is not justified without some serious backing.

Comment: This function is not only creating a temporary file, it creates a temporary directory for this one file. So even when the caller removes the temporary file later (and that is the reason why using a temporary file in the first place) then the temporary directory remains. So calling this function often will clutter the /tmp folder with garbage.

Answer (score 6):

Similar to [kinematic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15365656/65387), but with 2 bytes extra entropy and letters instead of numbers:

```
import Crypto from 'crypto';
import {tmpdir} from 'os';
import Path from 'path';

function tmpFile(ext) {
    return Path.join(tmpdir(),`archive.${Crypto.randomBytes(6).readUIntLE(0,6).toString(36)}.${ext}`);
}
```

Usage:

```
const file = tmpFile('tar.gz'); // "/tmp/archive.1scpz5ew5d.tar.gz"
```

I'm creating archives, so I chose "archive" as the basename, but you can change it as you see fit.

Comment: 16 bytes is a safer number - no collisions even if the use case is extreme

Comment: @ErikAronesty Sure, but node didn't support ints larger than 6 bytes at the time of writing. You can use 16 bytes in conjunction with ... actually we're still capped at 64 bits (`readBigInt64LE`). Looks like they still haven't added an arbitrary-length bigint method yet, but you could do it in 2 chunks if you want your 128 bits.

Comment: I convert Crypto.randomBytes(16) to hex, and call it a day.   Secure, fast, and not a problem.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can convert directly from a buffer to hex or base64, that works well. `crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')`

Comment: ```Path.join(tmpdir(),`${prefix}${Crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')}${suffix}`);}```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than a temporary file, it may be feasible to create a temporary directory using the built in libraries.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesmkdtempprefix-options

```js
import fs from 'node:fs/promises';

let folder = await fs.mkdtemp('foo-');
```

Knowing that the location you are working in, you can use constant names inside.

Answer (score -1):

use npm package [tempfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tempfile)

```
import tempfile from 'tempfile';
```

Or

```
let tempfile = "";
import('tempfile').then(a => {
    tempfile = a.default;
});
```

and then:

```
let filename = tempfile() //e,g: /tmp/5fc8a50f-e9cd-4420-b62a-e365b3ef2c2a
let imagefilename = tempfile(".jpeg") // e,g: /tmp/5a6dea08-a704-4fa8-9d0a-8ffa5e134543.jpeg
```