# How to pass very large argument to a nodeJS/phantomJS app from the command line

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line, phantomjs

I have a node app running in the background that needs to pass an HTML string too a PhantomJS app to create a render of it. That work fine but in some case the HTML is too long and i get a : `Argument List too Long` error message.

Here is the NodeJS code i use to spawn the phatomJS process:

```
var phantom = spawn('./phantom/phantomjs', ['./renderer.js', html, { detached: false });
```

Also since it's spawning a different process every time, it's very possible that many pages are rendering in parallel.

Any ideas on how this could be overcome ?

Comment: Pass a path to a file instead of file itself, try using `file://` protocol or just serve a page from `localhost`.

Comment: @elmigranto I've updated the question with a code sample. Can you post in an answer how you'd go about it ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are spawning Phantom from node. Instead of passing actual HTML markup to command line, save it to temporary file and pass path to that file. (You can use [some packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055061/nodejs-temporary-file-name) that provide temp file api to node.)

From there you can just `page.open()` that path with url like `file://<path-from-arg-list>`:

```js
// renderer.js
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'file://' + require('system').args[1];
page.open(url, function () {
  // …
});
```