# PDF to Image with Node and Meteor - How do I pass a buffer as an input file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, meteor, file-upload

I need to write an app where I can upload a PDF and then convert the first page to an image. I'm using the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-image.

Here is my client-side code:

```
'change #upload-materials'(event, template) {
    const file = template.$('[name=materials]')[0].files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
      Meteor.call('convertPDFToImage', reader.result, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
        console.log(result);
      });
    };
    ...
```

Here is my server-side code:

```
convertPDFToImage(file) {
  const pdfFile = new PDFImage(file);
  console.log(pdfFile);
  ...
```

The above doesn't work. According the documentation, I need to pass a path as the first option to create a pdfFile. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: do you get the solution??

i also have same problem

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that's possible with `pdf-image` package without creating a temporary file.

By briefly looking at their source code, one can find out that `pdf-image` is actually using `convert` to perform the transformation. Since **ImageMagic** allows using `stdin` instead of a regular input file (see [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)) one could theoretically use piping to pass the input/output data between the two processes. Unfortunately, `pdf-image` is not providing you with that option, so I guess the best way would be to write your own **ImageMagic** wrapper.

Comment: How do I create a temporary file with node so that I can write my own wrapper?

Comment: See if the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055061/nodejs-temporary-file-name) helps.