# Will an instance of a Google Cloud Run container overwrite temporary file?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am using Cloud Run with the default settings (80 requests per instance) running a container with node and express.

The service needs to create a temporary file when a request is processed. I'm wondering if when multiple requests arrive at the same time, will they be processed concurrently? So if the file is named the same thing, could it be overwritten by another process before the first one is completed?

With Node, I don't think we have parallel processes but I think there could still be a conflict unless express handles the requests sequentially.

Comment: There are no guarantees for concurrency. Requests can overlap. Create temp filenames with unique names. Most major languages support creating unique names. https://stackoverflow.com/q/7055061/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you! I hadn't even thought about the fact that I can auto generate unique temp names. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set `max concurrency = 1`, then you can use the same file name.

If you use `max concurrency > 1`, then you are at risk that multiple request would conflict when processing the file if using the same filename. The best is to use unique temporary filenames for each request and to ensure it is deleted at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll go with a unique file name to keep costs down and avoid cold start time.