# Upload very big amount data with nodejs

Tags: file, stream, upload, sequelize.js, large-files

I have a problem with uploading a very large amount of data in node js.
I don't know how to approach it all.

#### What i want to achieve?

On the client side, I select the CSV file to be imported. A file can contain a lot of records (even several million). On the backend I have to read data from it and then write this data to the database.

#### My doubts and ideas

1. I can't read the entire data at once, because then I will exceed the memory limit with one operation.
2. By breaking it down into smaller chunks, the request time will be very long, greater than the default, which is 2 minutes.
3. Is it a good practice to read hundreds of records from the stream and save them to the database? How is this achieved?
4. Maybe using some background process? I send the file and the request is completed immediately. Writing the file to the database happens in the background. Then I make a subscription on the client side, which listens to whether a given background process is over or not. Alternatively, I am sending the process progress.

#### My stack

graphQl, nodejs, sequelize

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer by addressing your doubts:

> I can't read the entire data at once, because then I will exceed the memory limit with one operation.

Definitely you need to be saving the data into the database as it is downloaded. The input file is a stream, so:

```js
http.createServer((request, response) => doSomething(request, response))
//                 ^^^^ - you can .pipe() this somewhere
```

The data will flow at the speed you consume it, so there's no need to worry about memory usage... at least that's what it seems. The truth is that if you use `on("data")` event, you'll consume data without any limit and will run out of memory.

> By breaking it down into smaller chunks, the request time will be very long, greater than the default, which is 2 minutes.

Well that depends on how fast your database is - but in general it may be true. You can however save the file do disk and start reading after it's uploaded - you'll probably have a bit more disk than memory, but that can also run out.

```js
http.createServer(async (request, response) => {
    const file = tmpfile() 
    request.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(file));
    request.on("end", async () => {
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end();
        await processFunction(fs.createReadStream(file));
        fs.unlink(file);
    });
})
```

Grab the [`tmpFile` function from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055061/nodejs-temporary-file-name).

I'm working on a module that will allow automatic spill-to-disk, but that's not done. I can update this answer later.

BTW, keep in mind that the user will not know if the upload fails. Node will easily handle a couple uploads at the same time and you can use the `cluster` module - so all that spilling to disk may be a bit too much and I'd recommend thinking about lifting that 2 minute timeout under some circumstances.

> Is it a good practice to read hundreds of records from the stream and save them to the database? How is this achieved?

It is a very good practice, better yet it is to insert multiple records at once, balancing memory usage and efficiency. If your records are not very heavy you can run even a 1000 inserts at the same time.

Out of laziness I'll use my own library [`scramjet`](https://www.scramjet.org), but you could use basic node.js streams - it is a hassle though so:

```js
async function processFunction(fileStream) {
    await sequelize.sync();

    await scramjet.StringStream.from(fileStream)
        .CSVParse() // you may need some options here
        .filter(x => checkIfDataIsOk(x)) // add some checking
        .batch(1000) // how many at the same time
        .do(group => User.bulkCreate(group)) // this will wait until it's saved
        .catch(errorHandler) // write some error handling.
        .run()

}
```

> Maybe using some background process? I send the file and the request is completed immediately. Writing the file to the database happens in the background. Then I make a subscription on the client side, which listens to whether a given background process is over or not. Alternatively, I am sending the process progress.

Yes you can, especially if you save the stream to a file, just invoke your program providing that filename and run it in background. I still recommend not loading everything into memory.

Comment: Thank You for the extensive answer but still i have some questions. 
Then I would like to write data to the database partially as You admitted (eg 1000 records). With on ("data") event I should create a temporary table and put records into it one by one, and then conditionally check if the length is equal to 1000 and write to the database? What in the case of the last batch of data, when there will not be 1000, and it will have to be saved to the database anyway? I cannot imagine such an implementation. Maybe I should use the Transform that stream offers for this?

Comment: The last batch will be simply as long as it is - no matter if it's 2 or 999. As to using `on("data")` - this will still cause the memory to pile up, so it's better to use scramjet or introduce some of kind of pause/resume. The temporary table is a good idea.